# How to handle null using refelection

Tags: c#, reflection

I am trying to set the value of object. I get the error because of `Object of type 'System.DBNull' cannot be converted to type 'System.Nullable1[System.DateTime]'` a. How to handle null using reflection.

I tried to solve like in described at the link but it won't help me.

I got this
[How to set property value using reflection in C#](http://technico.qnownow.com/how-to-set-property-value-using-reflection-in-c/)

```
    protected TEntity ToFirst(IDbCommand command)
    {
        using (var record = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            var items = new TEntity();
            while (record.Read())
            {
                items = Map<TEntity>(record);
            }
            return items;
        }
    }

    protected TEntity Map<TEntity>(IDataRecord record)
    {
        var objT = Activator.CreateInstance<TEntity>();
        foreach (var prop in typeof(TEntity).GetProperties())
        {
            var attributes = prop.GetCustomAttributes(false);
            var columnMapping = attributes.FirstOrDefault(a => a.GetType() == typeof(DbColumnAttribute));
            if (columnMapping != null)
            {
                var map = columnMapping as DbColumnAttribute;
                if (map != null && (record.HasColumn(map.Name) && record.IsDBNull(record.GetOrdinal(map.Name))))
                    prop.SetValue(objT, record[prop.Name]);
            }
            else
            {
                if (record.HasColumn(prop.Name) && record.IsDBNull(record.GetOrdinal(prop.Name)))
                    prop.SetValue(objT, record[prop.Name]);
            }
        }
        return objT;
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @mybirthname I am taking about using reflection. Read My Question

Comment: So do you have an exception with nulls or you want to improve your code, if you want to improve it this is not the correct place. See http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @mybirthname I am not asking for improvement. I am having issue regarding null values so I am looking for help.

Comment: Unclear. Who is null? What is the problem?

Comment: Shouldn't it be _NOT_ ? -> `!record.IsDBNull(record.GetOrdinal(prop.Name)`

Comment: as @Jeroen stated it seems like by doing record.IsDBNull(record.GetOrdinal(prop.Name) in both if conditions, you are only setting values of records with a null value

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Thanks! Sometime you stuck in simple thing but mind won't work.

Comment: @FanjoLama I know the feeling. Best way, like you did, is ask a fresh look of someone else.